# Remove text before specific character in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a document like this, so I want to remove text before : character on any line. Work in notepad++.

```
REMOVETHISTEXT:::REMOVETHISTEXT:DATA:DATA
REMOVETHISTEXT:::REMOVETHISTEXT:DATA:DATA    
REMOVETHISTEXT:::REMOVETHISTEXT:DATA:DATA    
REMOVETHISTEXT:::REMOVETHISTEXT:DATA:DATA
```

So what I want to save is `DATA:DATA`. How can I do this. thanks.

Comment: What makes the `:` between `DATA` and `DATA` different from the one between `REMOVETHISTEXT` and `DATA`?

Comment: i dont understand you , but what i want to remove is all the text and characters before DATA:DATA

Comment: You say "I want to remove text before : " but how can we tell which `:` there are many in the line.

Comment: Are `DATA:DATA` always at the 5th and 6th "columns"?

Comment: Also, after the removal: Should the line start by `DATA` or should It keep all the previous colons?

Comment: this is my document 
name:::dateofbirht:email:password i want to remove all words before email:password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having something like this in NotePad++

```
name:::dateofbirht:info@helpware.com:pwd
name:::dateofbirht:support@test.de:password
name:::dateofbirth:Steve.Ballmer@microsoft.com:password
```

you need to use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+):::(.+):(.+):(.+)`
- Replace with: `\3:\4`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

and you'll resulting in:

```
info@helpware.com:pwd
support@test.de:password
Steve.Ballmer@microsoft.com:password
```